# How to disable public CDN of O365 to particular site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, cdn

I have a site in which i have implemented master page and page layout using the custom css and js. I had given the relative URLs to reference the files in the Master Page.

After that, I enabled the public CDN to deploy the assets of SPFx web parts. The issue is that when I visit the site where I implemented the custom master page, now the css and js files are pointing to the public cdn urls and site stopped working.

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the master pages gallery is added as a CDN endpoint when public CDN is enabled.

You could use the Remove-SPOTenantCdnOrigin PowerShell command to remove the CDN.

But the change will be applied to all site collections. It is a tenant setting. 
There is a similar post:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/How-to-disable-public-CDN-for-particular-site-collection/m-p/138022

Remove-SPOTenantCdnOrigin.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spotenantcdnorigin?view=sharepoint-ps

More references:

General availability of Office 365 CDN.

https://dev.office.com/blogs/general-availability-of-office-365-cdn

Office 365 Public CDN Developer Preview Release.

https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release